# The most lightweight custom ROM?

Tags: rom

I'd like to remove the stock ROM and install a custom one. The smartphone has low operating memory - 512MB ram,so I think lightweight custom rom would be a good option. There are a lot of custom roms available but can't choose the right one,please help :)

The phone model is **Lenovo a316i**

Comment: Can you be more specific about your phone?

Comment: The phone model is Lenovo a316i

Comment: Try find AOSP ROM or Slim ROM for your phone model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly depend based on your phone model.. Yes as far as i know, SlimROM is minimal.. But im not sure whether it will be avilable for your phone.. Custom ROMs are not universal, it's device specific.. It is vary from device to device.. you can only flash a custom rom which is developed exclusively for your device.. you cant flash other phone's Custom rom to you.. it might lead you to hard brick your phone.. so before flash anythiong, research..!

Sorry i dont have enough reputation to post this as comment..!

Comment: The phone model is Lenovo a316i

Comment: as far as i know, there is no custom rom available for your mobile model.. sorry..